# Convert hours, minutes, seconds - cleaner code

Tags: javascript, refactoring

I created this function in javascript that converts between different time units. 

For example, calling `convertTimes(90,{symbol:"min"},{symbol:"hour"})` returns 1.5

```
function convertTimes(oldTimeValue, oldTimeUnits, newTimeUnits){
  const newTimeUnitSymbol = newTimeUnits.symbol

  if (oldTimeUnits.symbol === newTimeUnitSymbol) { return oldTimeValue }

  if (oldTimeUnits.symbol === "hour") { 
      if (newTimeUnitSymbol === "min") { return oldTimeValue * 60 }
      else if (newTimeUnitSymbol === "sec") { return oldTimeValue * 3600 }

  } else if (oldTimeUnits.symbol === "min") { 
      if (newTimeUnitSymbol === "hour") { return oldTimeValue / 60 }
      else if (newTimeUnitSymbol === "sec") { return oldTimeValue * 60 }

  } else if (oldTimeUnits.symbol === "sec") { 
      if (newTimeUnitSymbol === "hour") { return oldTimeValue / 3600 }
      else if (newTimeUnitSymbol === "min") { return oldTimeValue / 60 }
  }
}
```

Could you suggest a way of refactoring/cleaning this code so it doens't nest so many if-else calls?

Comment: You may want to check out [Code Review.](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Use http://momentjs.com. They've worked out all of the edge cases already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var conversions = {
hour: {
    min: 60,
    sec: 3600
},
min: {
    hour: 1/60,
    sec: 60
},
sec:{
    hour: 1/3600,
    min: 1/60
}
}

return oldTimeValue * conversions[oldTimeUnits.symbol][newTimeUnitSymbol]
```

Answer (score 1):

How about mapping symbol combinations to ratio?

```
const CONVERSION = {
  "hour:min":60,
  "hour:sec":3600,
  "min:hour":1/60,
  "min:sec":60,
  "sec:hour":1/3600,
  "sec:min":1/60
}

function convertTimes(oldTimeValue, oldTimeUnits, newTimeUnits){
  // TODO validate symbols
  if (oldTimeUnits.symbol === newTimeUnits.symbol) { return oldTimeValue }
  return oldTimeValue * CONVERSION[oldTimeUnits.symbol+":"+newTimeUnits.symbol];
}
```